# Function with sum equals function which uses digamma function

Tags: integration, summation, gamma-function, transformation, digamma-function

currently I am working on a Formular which I want to maximize. I tried to simplify the function with Wolfram. The Result was the following:

$f(k)=\sum_{i=k}^{n} \left( \frac{k-1}{(i-1)n} + \frac{(k-1)x}{(i-1)i} \right) = \frac{x(-k+n+1) + (k-1)\psi^{(0)}(n) - (k-1)\psi^{(0)}(k-1)}{n}$

With $k,n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in \mathbb{R}, 1 \leq k \leq n$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$

Actually I am not that deep into mathematics and never heard of the gamma or digamma function before. I looked up the Definition and some other stuff regarding to it, but nothing from which I could recreate this transformation.

Is there a trick to transform the function as given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be, you will feel more conformable with harmonic numbers since
$$\psi ^{(0)}(p)=H_{p-1}-\gamma$$ and

$$\sum_{i=k}^{n} \left( \frac{k-1}{(i-1)n} + \frac{(k-1)x}{(i-1)i} \right)=\frac{k-1}n\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac 1 {i-1}+(k-1)x\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac 1 {i(i-1)}$$ On the other hand, by telescoping,
$$\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac 1 {i(i-1)}=\sum_{i=k}^{n} \left(\frac 1 {i-1}-\frac 1 i\right)=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{n}$$

So
$$f(k)=\frac 1 n \Big(x (n-k+1)+(k-1)\left(H_{n-1}-H_{k-2}\right)  \Big)$$ which you wish to maximize (with respect to $k$ ?)

Comment: The approach does indeed make sense, I'll take a closer look at it later. 

n is a constant and x is a value which also depends on k. Strictly speaking, a different function. I want to know for which k between 1 and n the function is largest.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:$$\psi(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k-\gamma$$Where $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. The constant $\gamma$ is known as the Euler Mascheroni Constant. Plug this definition of the digamma function into the RHS of the formula you obtained and see what you get.

I think you got stuck because you were using $$\psi(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+n}\right)-\gamma$$

Comment: Yes that's right, I really tried to transform the formula using the lower one. If I see correctly, the suggested form is then also the one with the harmonic series, I will try to continue working with it.